# Ruby Eximporter error

Tags: ruby, rally

I get the following error when trying to run the ruby eximporter.rb to export things from rally.

```
'C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- stuff (LoadError)
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from eximporter.rb:26:in `<main>'
```

Any help will be very appreciated!

Comment: What's eximporter.rb? Is it a gem or one of your own files?

Answer (score 0):

Your version of Ruby is too new.  You need to use 1.8.7.p330.  When I made the mistake of running the latest version of Ruby, I got the same error.  When I downgraded to Ruby 1.8.7, everything worked.

Here is what the ExImporter documentation says: "Install the Ruby 1.8.7.p330 (nothing newer) Runtime Environment: http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/ (later releases of Ruby, such as 1.9.1 and newer, have a known issue in the way it handles the “fastercsv.rb” RubyGem and this discrepancy in behavior will cause ExImporter to fail at runtime)."

Answer (score 0):

just to add to this solution.  I did not have to downgrade my ruby installation. Instead I executed the following command `sudo gem install rally_api` and it worked for me just fine.